# {"code":14,"message":"Invalid value passed for authtoken."}

Tags: php, wordpress, zoho

I am trying to access zoho subscriptions through a wordpress api but I am getting the error above.

I have generated the Zoho-authtoken token but it seems like it wrong.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
$zoho_url = 'https://subscriptions.zoho.com/api/v1/subscriptions';

$organizationid = '644******';
$zohoauthtoken = 'c7e24e4efb1ffa******************';

$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'X-com-zoho-subscriptions-organizationid' => $organizationid , 'Authorization' => 'Zoho-authtoken '.$zohoauthtoken);

$response = wp_remote_post($zoho_url, array('headers' => $headers) );

print_r($response['body']);
```

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hard to debug without having zoho's credentials... Is it possible to access an URL like  `http://zoho-api-url/subscriptions?orgid=644&token=c7e24`? Also, maybe try `wp_remote_get` instead. Browsing the **[tag:zoho]** tag may be helpful as well.

Comment: Could you let me know how did you generate authtoken?

Comment: @brasofilo Let me try that

Comment: @Suresh I generated it from https://zapi.zoho.com/apigen.do

Comment: @BenShiundu: Please click the link in the following URL "https://www.zoho.com/subscriptions/api/v1/#authentication" to generate proper authtoken.

Comment: Thanks @Suresh, it worked!

Comment: I need to award you for the answer, @Suresh.

Comment: Thanks @BenShiundu :)

Comment: @Suresh I got the same issue I have generated the token via URL but this not working

Comment: @DsRaj : working now?